# Laravel 5 Controller Not working

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and doing something like this-

**app\Http\routes.php**

```
Route::get('test','DashboardController@delete_a_entry');
```

**app\Http\Controllers\DashboardController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function showProfile($id)
    {
        return view('layouts.customer.dashboard');
    }
}
```

**resources/views/layouts/customer/dashboard**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But getting this error

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because `DashboardController` doesn't have any `delete_a_entry` function.
You can fix this in two ways.

*Option 1.* Remove route

```
Route::get('test','DashboardController@delete_a_entry');
```

*Option 2.* Add this function to `DashboardController`

```
public function delete_a_entry()
{
    return 'some stuff';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the method does not exist.

Laravel is trying to find the method `delete_a_entry` when accessing in GET http://localhost/test/

I don't see this method in your controller, only a `showProfile`-method.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a method named `delete_a_entry`, like:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function showProfile($id)
    {
        return view('layouts.customer.dashboard');
    }

    public function delete_a_entry($id)
    {
        return 'some stuff';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your controller :

```
     public function delete_a_entry($id)
    {

 //here add you code to delete the entry
        return true;
    }
```